# Inserting a Complex Nested JSON Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, kubectl

Here is my use case :-
I am trying to get the deployment details in a JSON format using :
`kubectl get deployment -o json depl_name`
and inserting result back to a column: meta_data in MySQL. The column data type is json . But the insert statement is failing with error :-

```
ERROR 3140 (22032): Invalid JSON text: "Missing a comma or '}' after an object member." at position 1035 in value for column
```

Here is my entire JSON :-

```
{
    "uuid": {
        "view": "demoBoard",
        "demo": [
            {
                "serviceName": "wordpress-backend",
                "configurations": {
                    "ec2_iam": {
                        "user": [],
                        "roles": null,
                        "permissions": null
                    }
                },
                "deployment_config": {
                    "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
                    "kind": "Deployment",
                    "metadata": {
                        "annotations": {
                            "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "6",
                            "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"app\":\"wordpress-backend\",\"wordpress_app_id\":\"w26\"},\"name\":\"wordpress-backend\",\"namespace\":\"wordpress\"},\"spec\":{\"selector\":{\"matchLabels\":{\"app\":\"wordpress-backend\"}},\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app\":\"wordpress-backend\",\"wordpress_app_id\":\"w26\"}},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"envFrom\":[{\"configMapRef\":{\"name\":\"wordpress-backend-config\"}}],\"image\":\"docker-image\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"IfNotPresent\",\"name\":\"wordpress-backend\",\"ports\":[{\"containerPort\":8000}],\"resources\":{},\"volumeMounts\":[{\"mountPath\":\"/tmp/me/cloud\",\"name\":\"my-key\"}]}],\"imagePullSecrets\":[{\"name\":\"my-json\"}],\"volumes\":[{\"name\":\"my-cloud-key\",\"secret\":{\"defaultMode\":123,\"secretName\":\"my-key\"}}]}}}}\n"
                        },
                        "creationTimestamp": "2022-09-12T13:56:34Z",
                        "generation": 7,
                        "labels": {
                            "app": "wordpress-backend",
                            "wordpress_app_id": "w26"
                        },
                        "name": "wordpress-backend",
                        "namespace": "wordpress",
                        "resourceVersion": "v2",
                        "uid": "0da99b29"
                    },
                    "spec": {
                        "progressDeadlineSeconds": 600,
                        "replicas": 1,
                        "revisionHistoryLimit": 10,
                        "selector": {
                            "matchLabels": {
                                "app": "wordpress-backend"
                            }
                        },
                        "strategy": {
                            "rollingUpdate": {
                                "maxSurge": "25%",
                                "maxUnavailable": "25%"
                            },
                            "type": "RollingUpdate"
                        },
                        "template": {
                            "metadata": {
                                "creationTimestamp": null,
                                "labels": {
                                    "app": "wordpress-backend",
                                    "wordpress_app_id": "267"
                                }
                            },
                            "spec": {
                                "containers": [
                                    {
                                        "envFrom": [
                                            {
                                                "configMapRef": {
                                                    "name": "wordpress-backend-config"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "image": "docker.io/my-image",
                                        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                                        "name": "wordpress-backend",
                                        "ports": [
                                            {
                                                "containerPort": 8000,
                                                "protocol": "TCP"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "resources": {},
                                        "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                                        "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                                        "volumeMounts": [
                                            {
                                                "mountPath": "/my/path/cloud",
                                                "name": "my-key"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                                "imagePullSecrets": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "my-key"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "restartPolicy": "Always",
                                "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
                                "securityContext": {},
                                "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
                                "volumes": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "my-key",
                                        "secret": {
                                            "defaultMode": 123,
                                            "secretName": "sampleKeyName"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "availableReplicas": 1,
                        "conditions": [
                            {
                                "lastTransitionTime": "2022-09-29T15:11:14Z",
                                "lastUpdateTime": "2022-09-29T15:11:14Z",
                                "message": "Deployment has minimum availability.",
                                "reason": "MinimumReplicasAvailable",
                                "status": "True",
                                "type": "Available"
                            },
                            {
                                "lastTransitionTime": "2022-09-12T14:20:35Z",
                                "lastUpdateTime": "2022-09-30T14:13:08Z",
                                "message": "ReplicaSet \"wordpress-backend-abc123\" has successfully progressed.",
                                "reason": "NewReplicaSetAvailable",
                                "status": "True",
                                "type": "Progressing"
                            }
                        ],
                        "observedGeneration": 7,
                        "readyReplicas": 1,
                        "replicas": 1,
                        "updatedReplicas": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I guess, because of escape sequence in below line causing the failure :-
`"message": "ReplicaSet \"wordpress-backend-abc123\" has successfully progressed."`, tried removing that, but no luck.

Comment: You need to double the backslash.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, tried replacing the single quote with double quote for `"message": "ReplicaSet \\"wordpress-backend-abc123\\" has successfully progressed."` , still the same. Do I need to do the same for all single quotes ?

Comment: I never said anything about single quotes, just backslashes. You need to double all of them.

Comment: My bad. Sorry,  I meant the backslash. Let me try..